# How to get <img> tag from a blogger json-in-script file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, blogger

Im working with Blogger, and I need to get the last images from latest posts using the JSON feed API, in which you set the FEED mode to "json-in-script".

[Google Description of JSON BLOGGER API](http://code.google.com/intl/es-419/apis/gdata/docs/json.html)

I was studying the code, but I could not find any way to get what I want. I could extract media$thumbnails, but I need to resize the images, so I need the original size.

Does anybody knows?

Extra: How could I make jQuery works in Blogger?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery snippet that should help you.  It gets your feed, loops over the posts and grabs all the image references.  Once you have the image references in an array you should be able to process them as you want.  Don't forget to update the "feedURL" with your correct domain before using the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgArray = new Array(); // Holds array of images
    var feedURL = 'http://<yourdomain.com>/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=?';

    // Make ajax call to blogger
    $.ajax({
        url: feedURL,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            // Loop over each post
            $.each(data.feed.entry, function(idx, ele) {
                // Get image references
                var matches = new Array();
                if( (matches = ele.content.$t.match(/https?:\/\/.+?\.(jpg|gif|png)/gi)) != null )
                {
                    $.merge(imgArray, matches);
                }
            });
        }       
    });

    // do something with imgArray here
    // ...
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! The scripts works, but the problem is that most of the images are not and might not be hosted by google. So, I was thinking about doing a new RegExp, but, as I dont know RegEx, I will need some help. This new RegExp will search any character after "http://" any name, and .jpg,png.gif types: 
("http://"+*+/*.(jpg|png|gif)); I would be very grateful if you could change that expression, I hope you dont mind. Thank so much again!

Comment: No problem.  I update the regex to capture image references from any domain and not just those hosted on Google's CDN.

Comment: thank you, it is working great, but now I am trying to find the way to extract just one image/post, do you know how to match just one result? I was trying to do it with flags, but its going bananas, could you help me? Sorry, Im not too expert in javascript/jquery

Comment: That depends what you mean. All the images in an array so you can reference the first image by its position in the array at imgArray[0]. Or are you talking about using regex to only match in a single image? If so, do you have any specific matching criteria?

Comment: Im talking about using regex to only match in a single image. I dont know the criteria, because the image could have any name, be hosted in any domain, but must belong to different post, so I think, could it be solved using an array of array? or Is there any way to stop searching once an image was find, and continue with next entry? Thank you so much!